# Unable to change the gid in a user namespace

Tags: c, linux, namespaces

I wanted to set the uid and gid in a user namespace. The following code indeed sets the uid inside the namespace to 0, however the gid remains 65534 (group of nobody)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 0x10000

int x(void *arg) {
  sleep(3);
  system("id");
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  char uid_map[64] = {0};
  char gid_map[64] = {0};

  char* stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

  int pid = clone(x, stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, NULL);
  if(pid == -1) return -1;

  snprintf(uid_map, 64, "/proc/%d/uid_map", pid);
  snprintf(gid_map, 64, "/proc/%d/gid_map", pid);
  int uid_fd = open(uid_map, O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
  int gid_fd = open(gid_map, O_RDWR|O_CREAT);

  printf("%d %d\n", uid_fd, gid_fd);

  write(uid_fd, "0 1000 1\n", 9);
  write(gid_fd, "0 1000 1\n", 9);

  waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 4
uid=0(root) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)
```

How to set the gid correctly?

Comment: You should be using the `setgid()` function or system call, or one of its relatives (`setegid()`, `etregid()`).  You'll need appropriate privileges (meaning root privileges) if the GID is not one of the groups the process has listed in its auxilliary groups (`getgroups()`).  Setting the UID to other than the real or effective UID requires appropriate privileges too.  Using the `/proc` file system is probably not appropriate — it certainly won't work on most systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am able to set the uid to 0 with the proc filesystem as normal (unprivileged) user. The binary above doesn't have setuid bits turned on, that's why I can't use anything like `setuid()`, `setgid()`. It has to be possible to set the gid to 0 with the proc filesystem. This is also suggested by lwn (`https://lwn.net/Articles/532593/`)

Comment: You don't check the results of the `write` calls.  Maybe you should read the result back to check whether the change was effective in the `/proc` files.  An ordinary user cannot set the UID of a process to 0 effectively — that would be a major breach of security.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler first of all, have you read my question? It's about user namespaces. If the namespace/sandbox was created by an unprivileged user, the user can set the uid and gid of the process inside the namespace to 0. That worked half-way. I was able to set the uid to 0 as an unprivileged user that created the namespace. I only have problems with the group id. And indeed, the second write gives an error.

Comment: OK — you're out of my realm of knowledge.  You'll have to get someone else to help you.

Comment: this is the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692177/echo-to-gid-map-fails-but-uid-map-success